# Is collectAsStateWithLifecycle only applicable to cold flow, and not helpful for hot flow (e.g. stateFlow)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

Lately, we have a new API since android lifecycle library version 2.6.0-alpha01, i.e.

```
collectAsStateWithLifecycle(...)
```

It is advocated by Google Developer in this [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/consuming-flows-safely-in-jetpack-compose-cde014d0d5a3)

> If you’re building an Android app with Jetpack Compose, use the
> `collectAsStateWithLifecycle` composable function (instead of
> `collectAsState` )

I try it out, for flow (cold flow) e.g.

```
    val counter = flow {
        var value = 0
        while (true) {
           emit(value++)
           delay(1000)
        }
    }
```

It is useful to have

```
flow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(0)
```

But if we have a hot flow like mutableStateFlow

```
val stateFlow = MutableStateFlow(0)
```

It seems useless to have

```
stateFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(0)
```

given that it doesn't block any emission.

Am I right to state `collectAsStateWithLifecycle` only useful for cold flow, but not hot flow?

If I am wrong, can you show me an example where `collectAsStateWithLifecycle` is useful for hot flow too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is useful for any case where the flow relies on there being consumers for it to be hot.

In the case where you just do `val stateFlow = MutableStateFlow(0)` as you say, it would not change anything, no.

However one "hot flow" case where it matters, is where the flow becomes hot using the [stateIn](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/state-in.html) function, using the [WhileSubscribed](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-while-subscribed.html) policy as the [SharingStarted](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-sharing-started/) parameter of `stateIn`. Subscribing using `collectAsStateWithLifecycle` in that case means that the flow will not have a subscriber when the lifecycle is not at least [STARTED](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime-compose/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/compose/FlowExt.kt;l=95?q=collectAsStateWithL) or whatever you pass to `minActiveState`.

Comment: Nice! Thanks that's great. I got the answer from the Author too https://twitter.com/manuelvicnt/status/1587006978076938240